# WebSocket connection to 'protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

I was implementing laravel websockets package in project it is working fine in my local machine but on server first it was giving error of `Connection timeout` That problem was solved when add TCP port in aws security group but after that it starts giving new error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://52.64.101.38:6001/app/ABCDEF?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here are errors I am getting in console when try to connect websocket server
[image]

I was searching about this error i found this github thread . Which is saying try to bound with `0.0.0.0` but I dont know what does it means,

https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/issues/251

I was also getting this error on local machine but was later resolved when i downgrade package version 1.6

NOTE: I am using ubuntu server aws services

Comment: which channel can you please explain?

Comment: but it working on localhost

Comment: here is my routes ```Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Admin.Staff.{id}', function ($user, $id) {

    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});```

Comment: ok . let me test it . but it was working on localhost

Comment: still same error

Comment: yes that line is uncommented

Comment: ok. let me test it

Comment: i have checked your ip it  is working

Comment: have you cchecked console?

Comment: https://ibb.co/xG5LYYT see it is successfully subscribe to channel ready to listen

Comment: is it landing page?

Comment: yes i guess your calling 2-3 time so one get error but other is success

Comment: if you go on my_ip/laravel-websockets then try to connect and check console

Comment: Which you see is listening the channel it is five issue is when we try to trigger event

Comment: can you please share the link which you visited?